# Does one consumer thread against many partitions per topic in Kafka can cause latency?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Our kafka setup is as follows:

1. 30 partitions per topic
2. 1 consumer thread

we configured this way to be able to scale-up in the future.

we wanted to minimize the times we re-balance when we need to scale-up by adding partitions because latency is very important to us and during re-balances messages can be stuck till the coordination phase is done

Having 1 consumer thread with many partitions per 1 topic can effect somehow the overall messaging consuming latency?

Comment: more than latency i will be very slow consumption

Comment: @deadpool can you explain why? And what would be right balance between partitions and threads?

Comment: since there are 30 partitions and only one consumer thread is consuming, to increase the parallelism, you can consume one partition per thread of same group

Comment: But then if i add more machines it.will be.complex to to.stop.threads for the sake of other threads on other machines

Comment: are you using any spring framework? even you don't need that you can create multiple threads in one application

Comment: @Deadpool using vert.x created the kafka consumers ourselfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More partitions in a Kafka cluster leads to higher throughput however, you need to be aware that the number of partitions has an impact on availability and latency as well.

In general more partitions,

- Lead to Higher Throughput
- Require More Open File Handles
- May Increase Unavailability
- May Increase End-to-end Latency
- May Require More Memory In the Client

You need to study the trade-offs and make sure that you've picked the number of partitions that satisfies your requirements regarding throughput, latency and required resources.

For further details refer to [this blog post from Confluent.](https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-choose-the-number-of-topicspartitions-in-a-kafka-cluster/)

*My opinion: Make some tests and write down your findings. For example, try to run a single consumer over a topic with 5, 10, 15, ... partitions, measure the impact and pick the configuration that meets your requirements. Finally ask yourself if you will ever need `x` partitions. At the end of the day, if you need more partitions you should not worry about re-balancing etc. Kafka was designed to be scalable .*

Comment: the only problem is that  re-balancing can cause latency. and latency is something we are very sensitive about